# Instantaneous radiated EM power, integrate over an open or enclosed surface?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, electromagnetic-radiation, maxwell-equations, poynting-vector

It's about the propagation of an EM wave in the vacuum.

The instantaneous radiated power outcoming the volume $v$ is expressed as

$$p=-\iiint_v \frac{\partial w}{\partial t} \text{d}v=-\iiint_v \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\frac{\varepsilon_0}{2} E^2+\frac{1}{2\mu_0}B^2\right)\text{d}v=\iiint_v\vec\nabla\circ\vec P\text{d}v$$

where $\vec P$ is the Poynting vector. Through the divergence theorem, $p$ is expressed as

$$p={\Large{\unicode{x222F}}}_S\vec P\circ \text{d}\vec S$$

In most of references they integrate over an open and not enclosed surface, i.e.,

$$p={\iint}_S\vec P\circ \text{d}\vec S$$

Since $p$ is derived through divergence theorem which is (divergence theorem) defined with respect to an enclosed surface. So how one can simply express $p$ over an open surface ? Are there any hypothesis making the integrals over an open and enclosed surface the same in this case ?

Comment: This might just be a notational quirk (i.e. they got tired of writing the closed-integral symbol). Can you find an example where integration over an open surface is actually done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integration of the Poynting vector over a closed surface gives you the instantaneous *total* power a source radiates through that surface. Integration over an open surface gives just a fraction of the total power that goes through such surface.

If the source doesn't radiate at all directions, integration over a closed surface may reduce to integration over an open one. For instance, if it radiates only in the $\hat{z}$ direction, only a surface parallel to the $x$-$y$ plane will contribute to the surface integral.

Comment: About the first part of the answer: assuming some direction of $\vec P$, for a given surface $S$, $p$ cannot be the same if $S$ is considered a totally plane surface (open) or enclosed surface (for the same area, i.e. $S$).

Comment: About the first part of the answer: in this case, $S$ of the integral over an open surface is just a part of the $S$ of the integral over an enclosed surface since an enclosed surface can be divided into open surfaces, so the integral over an enclosed surface can be decomposed into many integrals over open surfaces.

Comment: Yes, use of different surfaces  (even of the same area) gives you different values for the instantaneous power delivered by the source. For some surface (open or closed), it gives the rate of energy flowing through that specific surface and that depends on the area of the surface, the value of $|\vec{P}|$ on the surface, and also on the angle between $\vec{P}$ and each $d\vec{S}$ filling the surface area.